# Add a function to all html elements

Tags: javascript, dom-events

You can make a video play by calling the `play()` function directly on the element.

```
document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
```

I want to setup similar functionality with my own custom function that will work with all html elements in the document.

I know I can bind a custom function to a single html element using [prototype](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp):

```
HTMLElement.prototype.myFunction = function() { ... };
```

However I want to bind `myFunction` to all html elements, and any new elements created.

Can I do this without looping through all the document elements and adding an event listener to listen for new elements which are created?

Comment: Putting a function on the prototype as you're doing will already achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: @CertainPerformance soooo..... wow... Thank you it works!